# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error using Group By Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I doing a few queries and I keep getting the same "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error. So here they are:

--Artist of the song that has the most streams

```
SELECT ArtistID, NumberofStreams 
FROM Songs 
GROUP BY SongID 
ORDER BY NumberOfStreams DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

--Returns oldest album and its Artist

```
SELECT ArtistName, AlbumName 
FROM Album 
ORDER BY ReleaseDate ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

--Returns Artist with the most songs

```
SELECT ArtistID, COUNT(SongID) 
FROM Songs 
GROUP BY ArtistID 
ORDER By COUNT(SongID) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Tables are set up like this:

Songs(SongID,ArtistID,SongName,SongName,SongLength)

Album(AlbumID,AlbumName,ArtistID,ArtistName,NumberOfTracks,ReleaseDate)

I think it has to do with my the ORDER BY or the LIMIT but I just cannot figure it out

Comment: *"I think it has to do with my the ORDER BY or the LIMIT"* If you thought so, why didn't you look at the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2126435) to find out? Then you'd *know*. Down-voting question for lack of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support `LIMIT`.  You can rewrite these with a subquery:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT ArtistID, NumberofStreams 
      FROM Songs 
      GROUP BY SongID 
      ORDER BY NumberOfStreams DESC 
     ) x
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Oracle 12c+ supports the much simpler and standard `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
      SELECT ArtistID, NumberofStreams 
      FROM Songs 
      GROUP BY SongID 
      ORDER BY NumberOfStreams DESC 
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```